# Authentication with Pear Auth() and access levels

Tags: php, authentication, pear

Looking on the web to find a good tutorial for implementing an auth system with Pear Auth(). I need to use different user permission, storing access level in a db field. On the official docs can't find anything about permission level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is signifying that you own an identity.  This is what PEAR Auth does.

Authorization is signifying that an identity has permission to perform an action.

***Authentication* is not *authorization***.

Take a look at [this previous question on good ACL classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370371/recommend-a-php-acl-class), which you can use to perform Authorization.

Comment: thanks for explanation, i'll take a look at the ACL classes... anyway i just found another pear package that can handle authentication and permission: LiveUser. Official docs is really poor...